# AWS Lambda TokenAuthorizer response error - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am creating a JWT token authorizer and I am nearly their I think, I just am getting an error when testing it.

So I created a Lambda token authorizer which will authorize a token on an incoming request to the gateway.

Here is the code:

```
const blahJWT = require("@custom/blah/authentication/blah");

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    try {
        let token = extractTokenFromHeader(event) || '';
        const webAuth = new blahJWT();
        await webAuth.authenticateWebToken(token);
        
        callback(null, 'Allow');


    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        // return {body: "Unauthorized", statusCode: 401};
        callback('Unauthorized');
    }
};

function extractTokenFromHeader(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    console.log(e.authorizationToken);
    if (e.authorizationToken && e.authorizationToken.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return e.authorizationToken.split(' ')[1];
    }
    else {
        return e.authorizationToken;
    }
}
```

However when I pass in a valid token through the api-gateway tester I get the following error:

```
Tue Sep 13 23:01:46 UTC 2022 : Authorizer result body before parsing: "Allow"
Tue Sep 13 23:01:46 UTC 2022 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid JSON in response: Cannot construct instance of `com.amazonaws.backplane.executioncore.frontend.authorizer.CustomAuthResponse` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Allow')
Tue Sep 13 23:01:46 UTC 2022 : AuthorizerConfigurationException
```

I am wondering if anyone can help solve this?

Thanks

Comment: can you check the event object properly, if the object keys are structured as the way you are extracting them

Comment: @Kaneki21, the structure is fine, and it is passing the authorization in the code, its just on the test side the occures

Comment: if it occurs while testing, then you have to prepare your test payload similar to the structure which you expect during production. Be it testing or production it will always expect same payload structure